# Twice differentiable function

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $ g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable. Assume

(a) $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$;

(b) $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $g
'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

How do I show $g(x) \neq 0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ ?

I need to show this in order to prove something else, but I can't work out how to.

Comment: Mean Value Theorem. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $g(x) = 0$ for some nonzero $x$. By MVT there is some $t$ strictly between $0$ and $x$ for which $0= \frac{0 -
 0}{x -0} = \frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x-0} = g'(t)$. But $g'$ is nonzero everywhere but at the origin, so necessarily we have $g'(t) \neq 0$. The desired contradiction is that $0 = g'(t) \neq 0$.

Comment: Part b) seems to repeat itself. Also, why do you need "twice differentiable"?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to assume $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R,$ $g(0)=0,$ and $g'(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$ Sketch: Either $g' > 0$ everywhere on $(0,\infty),$ or $g'<0$ everywhere on $(0,\infty).$ This follows from Darboux. In each case, you're very quickly done. Same argument on $(-\infty,0).$